# Why so much runtime difference for same algorithm?

Tags: java, python, performance

I did the interview street problem [string similarity](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4edb8abd7cacd). initially I did this in python.This gave me Time Limit Exceeded error for last 5 test cases. Then I tried the same one in java and the solution got accepted. The time difference between java and python versions for last 5 test cases were very high buts python beats java for first 5 test cases. Why is that so?

The length of string can go upto 100000.

stringsim.py

```
N=int(raw_input())
while N!=0:
    rootstr=[i for i in raw_input()]
    solution=0
    for i in xrange(len(rootstr)):
        for j in xrange(i,len(rootstr)):
            if(rootstr[j-i]==rootstr[j]):solution+=1
            else:break
    print solution
    N-=1
```

Solution.java:

```
class Solution{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Scanner sc=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    int N=sc.nextInt(),sol;
    while(N--!=0){
        sol=0;
        char[] s=sc.next().toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
            for(int j=i;j<s.length;j++){
                if(s[j]==s[j-i]) sol++;
                else break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sol);
    }
    }
}
```

```
Run time for java:
1               Success 0.172387
2       Success 0.172177
3       Success 0.172185
4       Success 0.172178
5       Success 0.263904
6       Success 2.82661
7       Success 4.66869
8       Success 4.83201
9       Success 1.36585
10      Success 1.02123

For python:
1       Success                 0.081229
2       Success             0.081047
3       Success             0.081032
4       Success             0.081015
5       Success                 0.910672
6       Time limit exceeded.    16.1818
7       Time limit exceeded.    16.2357
8       Time limit exceeded.    16.2001
9       Time limit exceeded.    16.2408
10      Time limit exceeded.    16.1831
```

Comment: And errr - what exactly is the **meaning** of the "solution" this code provides?

Comment: To improve your chances of getting an insightful answer, please post a link to the input file, and post your numeric time measurements as a table, highlighting which cells you find surprising. Without this data your specific question is very hard to answer.

Comment: Who is measuring these? Is the process restarted between each measurement (e.g. between 1 and 2)? If the process is restarted, then iccthedral's suggestion seems to be correct: it's most likely the JIT. For small inputs, by the time Python has came up with the answer, Java is still busy running the JIT. See my answer explaining what the JIT does.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with iccthedral's comment: the Java JIT can be a possible reason why Python is faster for the first few small inputs. To verify this, reverse the input order (so the large inputs come first), run it for all inputs in the same process, and measure the time again for each individual input. If Python is slow in that case for the last few (small) inputs, the presumption is confirmed.

Another way to verify it is to add the small inputs to the end as well (keeping them also in the beginning), and see how much longer it takes for Java to execute everything. If the delta is much larger than the execution time for only the small inputs, the presumption is confirmed.

The Java JIT compiles Java bytecode to machine code (which the CPU can execute directly and very quickly). But only those Java methods are converted in which Java spends lots of time executing them. (This is because converting all methods to machine code would be slow and the resulting machine code would need too much memory.) So when the Java process starts up, it starts executing all methods as bytecode, it measures how much time is spent in each method, and once a threshold is reached for a method, it uses the JIT to compile that method to machine code. After that, the method executes much faster. However, in the beginning of the process execution, all methods are slow, and for a short period of time the Java process becomes even slower, because it's busy with running the JIT.

It's likely that this is happening in your case: by the time Python has finished finding the answer for the simple problems, Java is still running the bytecodes or running the JIT to compile the bytecodes to machine code. But eventually Java will catch up, because machine code is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try to measure the time yourself in Java. I mean to count milliseconds inside main method. Do the same in Python. I guess the time in your answer is measured in OS - the time of java process running. The  time for first 5 examples may be mostly the overhead of starting JVM process.